# JQuery datepicker not sending selected value by posting in my asp.Net core application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

Please forgive me if I am asking a previously asked question. But I get stacked in this problem. Please help me.

I am using **jQuery datepicker** in my project. I can see the datepicker in browser well. But when I am **posting** only the selected value of datepicker not going to my PostAction where all other values are working properly. **Timepicker** also sending selected value Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

[This is my browser view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AJ5h.png)

[Script section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Ars.png)

[Form fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDlIY.png)

[Js and CSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyKTM.png)

[Model Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJr8S.png)

[Here is the posted value from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cOnq.png)

Answer (score 0):

The date format of `System.Datetime` was `dd-mm-yy`. But the date format of datepicker is `mm-dd-yy`. When I was selecting date from datepicker it was selecting a wrong value where format was not getting matched with the format of `model` property.

That's why I was facing this problem.